# npm ERR ELIFECYCLE and ETARGET

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

How do i fix these two errors? When i type in `npm start` it gives me this error:

> ```
> error Command failed with exit code 127.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! fuse-react-app@3.1.0 start: 
>
>     `yarn run tailwind && react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the fuse-react-app@3.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/comuterscience/.npm/_logs/2019-09-27T09_32_09_211Z-debug.log
> muddi:TjenerTeam_FrontEnd-master computerscience$
> ```

And if i type in `npm install` it gives me this error:

> ```
> npm ERR! code ETARGET
> npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for save-dev@^2.0.0.
> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
> npm ERR! notarget 
> npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'TjenerTeam_FrontEnd-master'
> npm ERR! notarget 
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/comuterscience/.npm/_logs/2019-09-27T09_38_45_318Z-debug.log
>         muddi:TjenerTeam_FrontEnd-master computerscience$
> ```

what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is because you are using the old version of npm. To upgrade it to the newer version, delete the file 'package-lock.json' and run 'npm install'.